# Improvement of simple regen receiver

Tags: transistors, radio, receiver

I recently designed and put together the following super-essential regen receiver:
[image: Radio schematic]

Rc,Re and Gain are potentiometers only so that I could get the biasing corrected. Sure enough the receiver works and picks up around 5 or so stations (here where I live, Northern Germany, the reception is not optimal).

First of all, I have two questions on this design:

- Which considerations go into determining the ratio between antenna/tuning coil and tickler coil turns? On a related note, what is a good number of turns if I would want to separate the antenna coil and the tuning coil?
- When I go from a very loud station to a weaker station there is a defined amount of time in which the sound is low and then rises slowly. I suppose is one of the capacitors that needs to readjust to a different voltage but which one is the main suspet?

Secondly I would like to improve the design but I'd like to keep it "modular". What I mean is that I want to add pieces to it to improve it without having to redesign the circuit from scratch. In this spirit, the tuning capacitor, the coil and the regen control are attached to the "main circuit" through crocodile clips, so that they can be exchanged or additional parts can be put inbetween or instead. So my question is, what would be good additions to the design?

Lastly, ideally I would like to have a multi-tap setup to receive multiple bands. Will the tickler coil work indipendently from which tap I take the signal  if it sits on top or near the beginning and the first tap of the "main" coil (I don't know if its clear but I can try to paint it)?

As a final note, I am aware of the designs of Kitchin but unfortunately I don't have a good and cheap source of JFETs so I will stick with the diode-resistor-capacitor detector.

Sorry for the long post!

Comment: Good luck in finding your answers of course. "I would want to separate the antenna coil and the tuning coil" - did you mean this or did you mean "antenna and tickler coils"?

Comment: I mean separated antenna, tuning and tickler. Or antenna and tuning, tickler and a third coil to the circuitry. Whichever is better actually, but three coils nevertheless

Comment: The usual — throw away your 1960's design and look at less ancient approaches? I don't really know how to improve a design that is a) already pretty complicated but b) depends on archaic components like Germanium diodes. So, seriously, an AM demodulator with modern, higher-gain BJTs is really nothing but a simple tunable circuit to select the RX frequency, followed by a rectifier (e.g. Schottky diode).

Comment: throw in as many gain stages built upon *modern* BJTs – not the ancient from whatever article that someone copied from someone else who copied it from someone else who copied it from his grandpa

Comment: or, really, since AM transmissions happen on pretty low frequencies only these days, what about simply ordering a free sample of a sufficiently high-bandwidth opamp with low input current and just have an adjustable RC up front to select frequency... ("Mittelwelle" hasn't been broadcast in Germany since 2015, so you're talking about "Langwelle", or "Kurzwelle". That's happening below 10MHz. That's basically DC for modern Radio people)

Comment: @MarcusMüller What are your modern BJTs? If for you Germanium diodes are archaic, I don't want to know what you think about vacuum tubes. Besides I would really appreciate if you would expand on your ideas in a proper answer. Because if you are here just to spew half knowledge like this and spit on my design than you are not being constructive

Comment: @Luca don't mean to annoy you! Point just is that this circuit has components in them that no-ione these days would use, and thus, the first things to do to improve things would be swapping out these. That will imply changes to the resistor values, and then you pretty quickly end up with a different kind of circuit you've started with. So, unless you explicitly state in which way you restrain how your circuit might be changed, I'd say, change everything but the antenna connector.

Comment: @Luca maybe this can be of inspiration to you: http://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1276286

Comment: (re: "modern" BJTs: the 2n5088 was specified and produced somewhen in the early 1970s; that's 40 years in the technological past. There's a lot of higher-current-gain, lower-noise, overall nicer transistors)

Comment: @MarcusMüller I didn't want to be unfriendly but it's clearly stated in my question what the constraints are, namely: "Secondly I would like to improve the design but I'd like to keep it "modular". What I mean is that I want to add pieces to it to improve it without having to redesign the circuit from scratch."
So if your first comment is "throw away", then either you are being rude or not reading completely the post (and therefore being rude), that's all...

Comment: @MarcusMüller
... I didn't know that in Germany MW is not broadcasted (that's why I didn't receive anything in german) but in the rest of the world it is. I.e. BBC still does, both MW and LW, and is coming lound and clear. If I want to listen to german radio, than I'll use the FM radio. The beauty of AM is to listen the rest of the world and not understanding a single word.
Regarding transistors, I don't know if it's in line with the posting policies but could you please throw at me some part no. or some specs I should look for? I have no clue what to look for in the ocean of transistors

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things that could be improved:

1. The tuning coil needs matching to the input impedance of the transistor - as shown the transistor will heavily damp the resonance causing the selectivity to be low.
   The normal way is to have a tap on the coil - probably about 1/5 to 1/10 of the way up from ground.
2. You need a path for DC at the input of the detector diode between C3 and the diode. A 10 k resistor would be a reasonable starting point.  Currently it is relying on the leakage current of the diode.

The RF will be rectified by the diode and charge up C3 such the the diode only just conducts - this could be the delay you are seeing. C3 doesn't need to be anywhere near as large as 10uF - it only has to pass the RF so 0.01uF or 1000pF would be my first choice. You could also add a small amount of forward bias to the detector with a high resistor to the +9v - maybe 470K or so would be a starting point.

You could also use a voltage double detector by using a diode instead of a resistor to ground.

3. You have DC going through your regeneration control - a 1000pF cap in series would be desirable.

There are many web sites with example circuits - there are also many in old magazines from the 1950's and 60s.  Many are online now - one particularly good effort is at [American Radio History](http://www.americanradiohistory.com/index.htm). One of my favorite magazines for this type of circuit can be found in Radio Constructor - an English magazine - [Radio Constructor](http://www.americanradiohistory.com/Radio_Constructor_Magazine.htm)

Comment: And I even thought about putting the resistor after C3 and of course forgot completely when I soldered everything together. The cap on the regen is missing only in the schematic :).
Thanks for the links, really interesting literature.

Answer (score 0):

Grab your free down-load copy of LTSpice and do some simulations. You can mimic the antenna pretty well because it is likely to be "short" at the low frequency you are using and it will therefore display a high tendency to look capacitive.

So, your antenna signal is going to be a few tens of micro volts RMS feeding through a capacitor that has a reactance of anything from 10 kohm to 1 kohm. 1 kohm capacitive is for an antenna whip (monopole) that is about one-fifth of one quarter wave: -

[image]

A weakness in your circuit design that makes it very tricky to predict the point where continuous oscillation occurs is the collector feed to the tickler coil - the collector has quite a large AC output impedance that presents to this node and, given that you have a variable resistor from this node to the tickler coil, it becomes difficult to analyse conventionally.

On the other hand trying to buffer that feed to the tickler is going to cause problems because the tickler coil has to be fed from a high impedance source to prevent it attenuating the signal from the antenna i.e. ideally you feed a current signal into the tickler. The way you have your circuit is a compromise in both directions but, to add another BJT seems to be going against the principle of a regenerative receiver because, if you can add another transistor then why bother using the regenerative technique.

You also have what I perceive to be a problem on the output of your detector - you are using a 10nF smoothing capacitor and a 10 kohm discharge resistor - this has a 3 dB point of only 1.6 kHz and you need this to be higher or you will get severe distortion and a somewhat smaller output signal - try 1 nF for C4 and not 10 nF.

LTSpice (or any of the usual sims) should offer an insight to the problem and possibly a more optimum solution.